# Submit select form item value - not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, sails.js

This is pretty basic stuff, so maybe I'm being blind to it, however I cannot get this working.

I've got a form, and part of that form has a Select item.  I've stripped out the inline JS and it looks like the following:

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="restaurantChain" name="restaurantChain" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="null">Not a chain</option>
    <option value="1234">12345</option>
</select>
```

Now, I submit this to a function which captures the data and I'm logging it out, however it's not working for the select item, everything else is fine:

```
var restaurantChain = req.param('restaurantChain');
```

I'm getting `undefined` but I cannot figure out why.  Here's my full code:

**Form**

```
<form method="post" action="restaurant-management/manage">
   <input type="hidden" value="<%= restaurant.id %>" name="restaurantId" id="restaurantId"/>
   <td><input type="text" value="<%= restaurant.name %>" name="restaurantName" id="restaurantName" class="form-control"></input></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="<%= restaurant.location %>" name="restaurantLocation" id="restaurantLocation" class="form-control"></input></td>
   <td>
      <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="restaurantChain" name="restaurantChain" data-live-search="true">
         <option value="null">Not a chain</option>
         <% if(typeof chains != "undefined") { %>
         <% _.each(chains, function(chain){ %>
         <option value="<%= chain.id %>" <% if(restaurant.chain == chain.id) { %> selected <% } %> >
            <%= chain.name %>
         </option>
         <% }) %>
         <% } %>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td class="text-center"><input type="submit" class='btn btn-info btn-s' name="editButton" value="Edit"> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-s" name="deleteButton" value="Delete"></td>
</form>
```

**Function**

```
manageRestaurant: function(req, res) {

  var restaurantName     = req.param('restaurantName');
  var restaurantId       = req.param('restaurantId');
  var restaurantLocation = req.param('restaurantLocation');
  var restaurantChain    = req.param('restaurantChain');
  var checkboxes         = req.param('checkboxes');

  console.log(restaurantName); //Works fine
  console.log(restaurantLocation); //Works fine
  console.log(restaurantChain); //Undefined....what?!
}
```

**Page Source**

```
      <tr>
        <form method="post" action="restaurant-management/manage">
          <input type="hidden" value="571c8ad57f18f8a441417a57" name="restaurantId" id="restaurantId"/>
          <td><input type="text" value="Nandos" name="restaurantName" id="restaurantName" class="form-control"></input></td>
          <td><input type="text" value="London - Oxford Street" name="restaurantLocation" id="restaurantLocation" class="form-control"></input></td>
          <td>
            <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="restaurantChain" name="restaurantChain" data-live-search="true">
              <option value="123">Not a chain</option>


                  <option value="571a0b7e09e2eff63befa5fa"  >
                    Nandos
                  </option>

                  <option value="571a0b8409e2eff63befa5fb"  >
                    McDonalds
                  </option>

                  <option value="571df9378fb28b8545ce4b23"  >
                    TGI Fridays
                  </option>

                  <option value="571dfb09f0e2af92456bc53f"  >
                    Subway
                  </option>


            </select>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center"><input type="submit" class='btn btn-info btn-s' name="editButton" value="Edit"> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-s" name="deleteButton" value="Delete"></td>
        </form>
      </tr>
```

**Answer**

If you still want to use a table, rather than restyling the page with CSS to get the same result, you can submit the form data using a Javascript function.  This gets the values from the elements on the page, and posts them.

Comment: When you submit the form, are you selecting one of the options? It won't be in the query string if you aren't. You would need to flag a default selected option by adding `selected` to the first `option`.

Comment: Yep.  The inline JS assigns a selected tag based on the dataset I'm using. Even when I select a new item and submit it, it's still undefined.

Comment: @4castle The first option is automatically selected by default if the HTML doesn't specify otherwise. So the value will always be included in the POST data.

Comment: In that case, it would always be 'null', however its undefined regardless of the option I choose.  I've just done a bit more debugging, and the reason it is undefined is because the select item isn't being included in the form submit :/

Comment: Can you dump all the parameters in the server? I don't know the sails.js syntax, but whatever is analogous to PHP `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: @Barmar I've just done that, and it's not even there.  For some reason, the Select statement isn't being included when I post the form:
{ restaurantId: '1',
  restaurantName: 'Nandos',
  restaurantLocation: 'London',
  editButton: 'Edit' }

Comment: It sounds like the `<select>` is not inside the `<form>`. I don't see why from the code you posted. Check the DOM inspector in the browser to see if they're properly nested.

Comment: Where are the `<table>` and `<tr>` elements in your HTML?

Comment: I've just checked the page source, and it's definitely nested the select inside the form.  I'll update the post

Comment: You can't have `<td>` as the child of `<form>`. The parent of `<td>` has to be `<tr>`.

Comment: @Barmar I've just posted the page source.  I have a <tr> and within that, <td> within the form

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have `<tr><form><td>`, it has to be `<tr><td>`.

Comment: So, how do you forms within table rows and columns?  I've never had this issue before :/

Comment: @Barmar - Just seen your duplicate.  Wow...I had absolutely no idea you couldn't do that!  Learn something every day! Thanks